# Accessing the Symfony user session in the model (Doctrine)

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony1, model, doctrine, symfony-1.4

How should one access Symfony's current user session in Doctrine's model?

The two ways (that I know of) to do it are to either pull it from the sfContext inside the model:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getCanSwim();
```

Or, pass the sfUser instance (or piece) directly to the model from the controller:

```
UserTable::goSwimming($sf_user->can_swim);
```

But, are any of these methods better than the other, or is this not the correct way to do it all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this kind of situations, you should consider using the [Dependency Injection design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) as Fabien Potencier [clearly explains](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection).

The idea is that you have to *inject* into your dependant object all of its dependencies such as -in your case- the user or the context.

That (the second option) would be the less MVC-killing way, afaic.

Answer (score 5):

This might be of interest:

http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/

Comment: I've seen that article but have wondered both ways. People seem to suggest the opposite, but I was curious other's take on the 'correct' way.

Comment: I use sfContext occassionally when it seems like a convenient solution but I think your case (as you're dealing with a class), it's better not to use it so it doesn't break when using tasks etc.

Comment: Tom - I'm curious. when is it ever a convenient solution?

Comment: @Jamie... for example when loading a Symfony helper inside a custom helper class. For example, I might have a custom helper that renders pagination links at the bottom of different SERPs, and I need access to the Symfony URL helper to call url_for@ or link_to@ instead of hardcoding routes. This helper would only ever need to be called when rendering templates. But I'm sure there's someone out there who'd tell me I should do some other object-oriented this or that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency Injection is an exceptional context, but I think that sometimes it's an overkill.

Why implement an additional method, or override a constructor, if the only thing you need, in your example, is to know if the current user can swim?

So, IMMO, if the use-case is simple, you can very well go for the second option that you've provided, and lower the dependency to just the value that it depends on:

```
goSwimming($sf_user->can_swim);
```

---

Of course it all depends on the actual concepts used and in how extended does one class depend from the other.

If it's just this case (result depending on user's hability to swim), than it's ok to simplify. But if the called method/class can eventually make use of more attributes, than it's probably best to go with the Dependency Injection technique that was already discussed. UserTable is probable to depend on the sfUser for other things, so this feels like a full class-dependency.